# Filtering a queryset with foreign key value in ListView

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I am trying to filter a queryset by setting the value of the foreign key equal to a url slug.

## models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):

    parent_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)

    parent_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class Child(models.Model):

    child_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40, default=1)

    child_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=1)

    parent_slug = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = 1)
```

## urls.py

```
from .views import ChildListView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<parent_slug>/children/', ChildListView.as_view(), name='child_list'),
    ...
]
```

## views.py

```
class ChildListView(ListView):

    template_name = 'child_list.html'

    context_object_name = 'child'

    def get_queryset(self):

        slug_param = self.kwargs['parent_slug']

        qs = Child.objects.filter(parent_slug = slug_param)

        return qs
```

This is the error result:

Exception Value:
Cannot resolve keyword 'parent' into field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter on the `parent_slug` of the `Parent` object (which is referred to as `parent_slug`), so you filter with:

```
class ChildListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'child_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'child'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Child.objects.filter(parent_slug__parent_slug=self.kwargs['parent_slug'])
```

That being said, the nomenclature in the modeling is a bit *odd*. Usually fields are *not* prefixed with the name of the model, and a `ForeignKey` refers to an object of the model to which the field refers, not its slug. It furthermore probably does not make much sense to set `default=1` for a `ForeignKey`, since that could later refer to a different object than the one you are holding. Finally setting `default=1` to a `SlugField` definitely does not make much sense.

Probably a better way to define your models is:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

we can even abstract the `name` and `slug` away in an abstract base model (for example `NameSlugModel`), like:

```
class NameSlugModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Parent(NameSlugModel):
    pass

class Child(NameSlugModel):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In that case, you filter with:

```
class ChildListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'child_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'child'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Child.objects.filter(parent__slug=self.kwargs['parent_slug'])
```

Comment: Thanks, Willem! Great point to abstract away the NameSlugModel. I will implement that. Also the explanation of the query filter is clear. It has raised two other issues for me which I will post separately.

Comment: Willem (or others), what are other good standard abstract models to include? I’m probably gong to include a date time stamp abstract class as well. Anything else to consider?

Comment: @DavidGoldman: usually if it is a sensical set of attributes, that might have certain behavior. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes There are some GitHub projects that define a set of base-classes, like https://github.com/concentricsky/django-basic-models

Comment: @marc_s: please do not change the code blocks, the `<b>` is meant to show bolface in the code blocks, not `<b>` in the code.